# iOS Table View - How to divide/filter different data

Tags: tables, ios, filter

I'm wondering what the preferred choice would be to divide/filter data in an [iOS Table View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451). The two options I have thought of are:

- Use sections in the Table View
- Use a Segmented Control

I believe the amount of data will probably be around 1-10 for each filter for the normal user.

The context of this application is a utility application that users will pay for to download.

Comment: What context is this in? What will the data be used for? (Also, for people unfamiliar with what an iOSTable View is, could you provide pictures as examples?)

Comment: @dhmholley Added a link...

Comment: @PeterWarbo: please have a look at What makes a good question:  http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#what-makes-a-good-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a general answer that works in all scenarios. Both your suggestions are fine. There are also other options, like tabbing, typing, and multiple toggle buttons to combine filters. But it all depends on what you want to achieve.

I guess you already had a look on existing designs for inspiration. In sake of question asking, it helps if you post your thoughts on design choices so far, what you have tried, what did not work out, and why.